Locally free sheaf with global section is an extension
Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $n \geq 2$ on a scheme $X$. Suppose $\mathcal{E}$ admits a global section $s$ whose vanishing locus has codimension exactly $n$ in $X$. Is it true that $\mathcal{E}$ is an extension of locally free sheaves? I.e. is there an exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal{E}' \to \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E}'' \to 0$ where $\mathcal{E}', \mathcal{E}''$ are locally free? I'm interested in the case where $X$ is smooth over field, so you can assume that if needed.
My thinking is that, given trivializing open subsets $U$ and $V$, the section $s|_{U \cap V}$ defines a basis over which the transition matrices of $\mathcal{E}$ are diagonal. So it should be possible to construct an extension in this way. Is that right?

No. For instance, the sheaf $T(-1)$ (the tangent sheaf twisted by $-1$) on $\mathbb{P}^2$ has a global section vanishing at exactly one point, but it is not an extension of line bundles, because any such extension splits, while $T(-1)$ is indecomposable.
